# How to group_by multiple variables into a single operation

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

I have this fata frame Xi, I need to make a new one which reflects the following operation:  the `trade_value_usd` in Xi (grouped by reporter and commodity, as in Xi) / the sum of `trade_value_usd` of all commodities, grouped by reporter

```
> head(Xi)
   reporter    commodity trade_value_usd
1   Algeria Live animals           11075
2   Andorra Live animals          120732
3 Argentina Live animals         8057242
4 Australia Live animals       634849604
5   Austria Live animals        60349499
6   Bahrain Live animals          280601
```

I tried

```
 SH <- Xi %>% group_by(reporter, commodity) %>% summarize(SH = trade_value_usd) / sum(trade_value_usd))
```

Final result should look something like this:

```
> SH
# A tibble: 168 x 2
   reporter      SH
   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 Albania      0.6
 2 Algeria      0.2
 3 Andorra      0.5
 4 Anguilla     0.9
 5 Argentina    0.1
 6 Armenia      0.8
```

Comment: what is the difference between reporter and country?

Comment: no one, my fault . i fix it

Comment: The first `group_by` seems unnecessary. You simply group and perform no operation? Could you add some more data, maybe two values for each?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to use group_by, values of what?

Comment: it give me error Column `sh` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 87

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(reporter) %>% 
  mutate(trade_volume_per_reporter = sum(trade_value_usd)) %>% 
  group_by(reporter, commodity) %>% 
  summarise(trade_value_usd / trade_volume_per_reporter)
```

Comment: not really, I need unique values in reporter, each row must be the sum of all divisions for each country

Answer (score 1):

If you need sum of usd per reporter

```
# artificial data generation
set.seed(4422)
Xi <- tibble("reporter" = rep(LETTERS[1:10], 2), 
             "commodity" = sort(rep(letters[1:2], 10)), 
             "trade_value_usd" = ceiling(runif(20, 6000, 450000))
             )

countrySum <- aggregate(trade_value_usd ~ reporter, Xi, sum)
countrySum
   reporter trade_value_usd
1         A          679399
2         B          794578
3         C          176858
4         D          697695
5         E          528665
6         F          496006
7         G          635249
8         H          824737
9         I          619079
10        J          640500
```

If you need usd fraction of each commodity per reporter (sum of fractions for each reporter is 1) could be

```
# Fraction of usd by reporter
SH <- NULL
# need as.factor because Xi is a tibble
countries <- levels(as.factor(Xi$reporter))
for (i in seq_along(countries)) {
  uu <-as.vector(
      Xi[Xi$reporter == countries[[i]], 3] / sum(Xi[Xi$reporter == countries[[i]], 3])
    )
  names(uu) <- "fraction"
  SH <- rbind(SH, cbind(Xi[Xi$reporter == countries[[i]], ], uu))
}

> SH
   reporter commodity trade_value_usd  fraction
1         A         a          426532 0.6278078
2         A         b          252867 0.3721922
3         B         a          345296 0.4345653
4         B         b          449282 0.5654347
5         C         a          100431 0.5678624
6         C         b           76427 0.4321376
7         D         a          335791 0.4812862
8         D         b          361904 0.5187138
9         E         a          141603 0.2678502
10        E         b          387062 0.7321498
11        F         a          212146 0.4277085
12        F         b          283860 0.5722915
13        G         a          409227 0.6441994
14        G         b          226022 0.3558006
15        H         a          397377 0.4818227
16        H         b          427360 0.5181773
17        I         a          230093 0.3716699
18        I         b          388986 0.6283301
19        J         a          327676 0.5115941
20        J         b          312824 0.4884059
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

reporter <- rep(c("Algeria", "Andorra","Argentina","Australia","Austria","Bahrain"), 2)
commodity <- c(rep("Live animals", 6), rep("Maize",6))
trade_value_usd <- c(seq(from=5000, to=60000, by=5000))
Xi <- cbind.data.frame(reporter, commodity, trade_value_usd)

Xi

    reporter    commodity trade_value_usd
1    Algeria Live animals            5000
2    Andorra Live animals           10000
3  Argentina Live animals           15000
4  Australia Live animals           20000
5    Austria Live animals           25000
6    Bahrain Live animals           30000
7    Algeria        Maize           35000
8    Andorra        Maize           40000
9  Argentina        Maize           45000
10 Australia        Maize           50000
11   Austria        Maize           55000
12   Bahrain        Maize           60000


Xi %>%  group_by(commodity) %>%
  mutate(sh = format(round(trade_value_usd/sum(trade_value_usd),3),
                     nsmall = 3), trade_value_usd=NULL)



   reporter  commodity    sh   
   <chr>     <chr>        <chr>
 1 Algeria   Live animals 0.048
 2 Andorra   Live animals 0.095
 3 Argentina Live animals 0.143
 4 Australia Live animals 0.190
 5 Austria   Live animals 0.238
 6 Bahrain   Live animals 0.286
 7 Algeria   Maize        0.123
 8 Andorra   Maize        0.140
 9 Argentina Maize        0.158
10 Australia Maize        0.175
11 Austria   Maize        0.193
12 Bahrain   Maize        0.211
```

Comment: With this I get only 0.000s

Comment: Maybe I id not explain well. There are many characters values in commodity. I need to sum all o totem per each reporter. Final df shall be with reporter and the new variable

Comment: Maybe you should include an example containing different values in commodities for each reporter. I understand you need the cost fraction for each commodity within a reporter. If so, your output will have the same number of rows that the original df. Is this correct?